# Laravel 5 datapicker suggestion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, laravel-5

Do you have any suggestion about using datapicker in Laravel 5?

I find few, but with problems when try to use:

1.https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

2.http://getfuelux.com/

Answer (score 0):

I withdrawn my idea, and use standard Jquery datapicker:

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default

And,work fine...

Tnx all